# Not able retrieve Azure graph token from global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, global-asax

I am on working on MVC application and I am able to fetch the graph token from controller but same code(PFB code) is not working in Global.asax.cs

It is not giving any error but it is paused at **authContext.AcquireTokenAsync** and it is not moving forward.

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tenantId = "TenantId";
            string clientId = "CleintId";
            string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId);
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", credential);
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Could any one please help me here.

Comment: Ha ha it will never execute @Avinash its a `Void` method. Your code seems okay. Try with another cs file with async method hope will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync` is a asynchronous method, so it will wait and not move forward until it is finish.

Use the code as below in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected async void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId);
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationResult result =authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", credential);
    var accesstoken = result.AccessToken;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just be aware that async void is "fire and forget" so the continuation will run after the method has already returned in a bit of an odd state since exceptions thrown won't be caught by the framework component calling this function.

Comment: I don't think the `async` is needed since in the sample code you're just calling `.Result` which will block untill finished. It is needed on in the screenshot though since the code doesn't match